# If $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x a(t)\,dt=L$, is it true that $\lim_{x\to\infty}a(x)=0?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

Let $s(x)=\int_0^xa(t)\,dt$. I wonder:

If $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}s(x)=L$ is it true that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}a(x)=0?$

Comment: You need to have some more assumptions, because at the moment the function $$a(x) = \begin{cases} 7, x\in\mathbb{N} \\ \frac{1}{x^2}, otherwise \end{cases} $$ is a counterexample.

Comment: The integral could "act" like a convergent alternating series. E.g., $\int_0^\infty\cos x^2\,dx$ converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One hypothesis that does yield this result is that $a$ is *absolutely* integrable and uniformly continuous. Comparing to Martin R's answer, uniform continuity makes it so a triangle of a fixed height cannot be arbitrarily narrow.

Edit: a sketch of a proof. Suppose $f$ is absolutely integrable, uniformly continuous, and it is not true that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. Repeatedly apply the definition of the last statement to get $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ with $|f(x_n)| > \varepsilon$ and $|x_n-x_{n-1}| \geq 1$. Use uniform continuity to get intervals $I_n$ centered at $x_n$ with $|f(x)| > \varepsilon/2$ on $I_n$, where the $I_n$ all have length at least $\delta$. (When assuming only continuity, we cannot assume that the $I_n$ all have length at least $\delta$, which is why Martin R's example works.) Derive a contradiction of the absolutely integrable hypothesis from here.

This still works if you replace the absolute integrability with improper Riemann integrability, because in that case the integral would have to diverge either to $\pm \infty$ or by oscillation. This is because we guarantee that the integral over $I_n$ is at least a fixed number, namely $\varepsilon \delta/4$. We do not guarantee that it is at least, for example, $1/n$.

Comment: That sounds plausible. Can you give a hint how one would prove it?

Comment: @MartinR I edited in a sketch of a proof. This was actually a problem on a qualifying exam at my university. :)

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false even for continuous non-negative functions.
As an example, consider the function $a: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ whose
graph consists of triangles with baseline $[n, n + 1/n^2]$ and height $2$
for each $n \in \mathbb N$ and is zero otherwise.
Then $\int_0^\infty a(x)dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2 = \pi^2/6$,
but $\lim_{x \to \infty} a(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Nice construct.

Answer (score 2):

No. $\lim_{x\to\infty} a(x)$ need not even exist, $a$ could be $1$ in a set of measure zero.